# No AuthenticationProvider found with Adding new AuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a very simple Spring Boot application with Spring Security that uses formLogin and an inMemory user detail manager, and everything works perfectly. However, when I tried to add another provider, which is not used anywhere, the app throws a 'No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken' exception. My Authentication Provider's override method always returns false, which means the ProviderManager will not use it in any case. Also, removing the @Component annotation from MyAuthenticationProvider also works as expected.

My understanding is, in-built UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is linked to DaoAuthenticationProvider, and Spring Security will find this DaoAuthenticationProvider. However, just adding another dangling provider is not finding DaoAuthenticationProvider, and I wonder why it is throwing this error. Below are the configuration and code snippets I used.

1. Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

2. Added Authentication Provider

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("Dummy");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you specify your `AuthenticationProvider` Spring Security assumes that you do not want any of its default providers and will use only yours. If you look at the `DaoAuthenticationProvider#supports` method you will see that it supports the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` (which is used by `formLogin`). On the other hand, your `MyAuthenticationProvider` does not support any type of `Authentication` object, that is why Spring Security is throwing that exception.

You can fix that by making `MyAuthenticationProvider#supports` return `true` or return a boolean value based on the `Authentication` object.